# Detecting level in a Pulse Train

Tags: sampling, signal-detection

Assume I have a square wave pulse train, where each high lasts for ***H*** and each low lasts for ***L*** seconds. I sample this waveform and have the sequence of numbers.

Question is what should be the sampling rate if I just want to know what level I am in(High or Low)?

I know by Nyquist I can find the sampling rate for full-reconstruction of the pulse train, but I don't need the full reconstruction. I just want to be able to:

**1. Don't miss any High or Low**

**2. Detect all Lows and Highs**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum level time (i.e. minimum of L and H) must be greater than the sampling period. This way, there is no possibility for a pulse to be missed.

So, $T_s < \rm{min}(L,H)$.